# When do a dungeon path counts as a daily path - In its beggining or end?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I think the best way to ask this question is with an example.

We all know [the server reset its dailies in midnight UTC](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81762/when-do-the-daily-achievements-reset), so, let's suppose it's the day of the lord **17 Jan 2012, 11:45 UTC**, I'm with a group and we start Ascalonian Catacombs Dungeon doing the Path 1. But we just finish it at **18 Jan 2012, 00:15 UTC**. The question is, for which day do this run counts? Does it count as a daily run for **17 january or 18 january**? In its beggining or end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dungeon rewards count only when you actually complete the dungeon.

This includes achievements, as well as monetary and xp rewards.

So in your hypothetical case, above, it would count for the 18th of January.